# How to get ServiceM8 attachment download link/file data through API

Tags: api

In Service M8 while submit forms I can attach images and those are saved as an attachment. I can get the attachment ID for that image through API and webhook. Now I want to send this photo through email.

How can I get the file link/file data from the Attachment object.

Here is a sample attachment API response

```
{
  "uuid": "0c7b6f95-fcb7-483d-8805-9e3547f6d31a",
  "edit_date": "2017-01-12 10:59:01",
  "active": 1,
  "attachment_name": "Photo",
  "file_type": ".jpg",
  "attachment_source": "PHOTO",
  "lng": 0,
  "lat": 0,
  "tags": "",
  "created_by_staff_uuid": "c0b476c2-d5b5-4e21-96a9-7088689e778b",
  "timestamp": "2017-01-12 10:58:59",
  "related_object": "formresponse",
  "related_object_uuid": "340a5289-79ff-4583-b7eb-7ed2680b81ba"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Add `.file` to the end of the URI:

**Instead of calling this:**

- ```
   https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/Attachment/0c7b6f95-fcb7-483d-8805-9e3547f6d31a
  ```

**Call this:**

- ```
  https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/Attachment/0c7b6f95-fcb7-483d-8805-9e3547f6d31a.file
  ```

Which would return a link that looks like this:

- ```
  https://data-cdn.servicem8.com/attachments/servicem8_xxxxxx/dbo_uuid.ext?expires..etc.
  ```

`.ext` in your case is `jpg`, but a PDF for instance would return `.pdf`